# Moodle : local plugin lang. folder

Tags: moodle

I have created a local plugin. Inside lang folder, parallel to en folder, I placed a folder zh_cn for chinese and put chinese strings in local_pluginname.php file.

What is the langconfig.php file. Is it needed every time or only for installation of language pack.

Moodle version 2.8.5

Please help.

Comment: Its for the installation of a language pack. It will be downloaded into `yourmoodledatafolder/lang/langcode/` when you install a language pack.  You only need to create a `langconfig.php` file if you need a language pack that isn't already available, but there are already over 100 language packs available - https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Language_packs

Comment: Thank You fo the Info, i did not get this elsewhere . Please answer instead of comment so that i can accept answer. Also  have another issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704515/moodle-language-change-when-on-inner-pages    Thanks in advance for any help.